# Host ASP.NET Core MVC on local PC with IIS, host on local PC with local DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, localdb

I made a asp.net core application and I need to host it on local PC with local DB. For test I deploy and host it on my PC with IIS and it's working without  problem but only with online DB, when I change connection string to my local DB I got this error: [error with local database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxKBe.png%C2%B8)

and here is my connection string for online ( working normally) and local db ( don't work when deploy, work in visual studio)

[connection strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAQoU.png)

what I need to install/change to host my app on local PC with local DB

Comment: So application and database runs on the same computer but if application tries to connect to local database it crashes. And it its connect to online db it works fine. Am I getting it right?

Comment: Yes, but only when deploy and host app with IIS

Comment: Looks like the user account under which the iis runs doesn't have access to local sql server. Instead of `Trusted_Connection =true` try putting username and password of the actual database user in the connection string.

Comment: I tried it now but nothing, same error again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem but forget to post here

I need to create new sql user with privileges to my db and set connection string like this:

```
    "Name": "Server=localhost; Database=myDB; Trusted_Connection=false; MultipleActiveResultSets=false;User ID=UserName; Password=UserPass;"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use SQL Server Express for this, not Localdb. Localdb is for VS and single desktop app use only .

Comment: and how do I need to set connection string for sql express and IIS manager


I just need to deploy and use my app on local PC ( no internet connection)

Answer (score 0):

Today I tried with sql express and localDB instance but I don't know how to set it. I was try some variations but unsuccessfully, I can't find tutorials for that.

Is it possible at all to host ASP.net core MVC to IIS and use local database ? My app will run on PC without connection to the internet so I need to put database locally